# FactoryGirl creating extra records with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm running into an issue where FactoryGirl appears to be creating extra records with a has_many relationship.

Given these models:

```
class NextAction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :next_actions_orders
  has_many :orders, through: :next_actions_orders
end

class NextActionsOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :next_action
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :next_actions_orders
  has_many :next_actions, through: :next_actions_orders
end
```

And these factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :next_action do
    status :pending

    trait :pickup do
      next_actions_orders { FactoryGirl.create_list(:next_actions_order, 1) }
      action_type :pickup
    end

    trait :multiple_pickups do
      next_actions_orders { FactoryGirl.create_pair(:next_actions_order) }
      action_type :pickup
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :next_actions_order do
    order { FactoryGirl.create(:order) }
    next_action
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :order do
    status :pending
  end
end
```

As you can see in the NextAction factory, I ran into an issue setting up the NextActionOrder association.

I would usually have used `next_actions_orders { FactoryGirl.create(:next_actions_order) }` but with the `has_many :next_actions_orders`, I was getting an `undefined method 'each' for #<NextActionsOrder...` error.

`next_actions_orders { FactoryGirl.create_list(:next_actions_order, 1) }` seems to work as a workaround.  As shown below, this doesn't seem to be the cause of the issue, since it also exists from the `create_pair` example.

The real issue is this:

```
it 'create_list generates duplicate FactoryGirl records' do
  puts NextAction.count # output: 0

  pickup = create(:next_action, :pickup)

  puts NextAction.count # output: 2

  ## binding.pry
end
```

Succinctly, the `create(:next_action)` calls seem to be generating 1 additional NextAction record than is required.

I used pry to inspect this and sure enough, you can see this.

With pry inserted at the first location shown above, queries produce the following:

```
pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>)> NextAction.all
=> [#<NextAction id: 2, ... created_at: "2014-04-20 16:40:57", updated_at: "2014-04-20 16:40:57", status: 0>,
 #<NextAction id: 3, ... created_at: "2014-04-20 16:40:57", updated_at: "2014-04-20 16:40:57", status: 0>]
pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>)> NextActionsOrder.all
=> [#<NextActionsOrder id: 1, next_action_id: 3, order_id: 2>]
pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>)> Order.all
=> [#<Order id: 2, created_at: "2014-04-20 16:40:57", updated_at: "2014-04-20 16:40:57", status: 0>]
```

Here, everything looks great, except for NextAction ID #2.  It's not associated anywhere, it's just an orphan record that was created for some reason.

Here's what happens with `create_pair`:

```
it 'create_pair generates duplicate FactoryGirl records' do
  puts NextAction.count # output: 0

  pickups = create(:next_action, :multiple_pickups)

  puts NextAction.count # output: 3

  ## binding.pry
end
```

With pry inserted as shown, the same queries produce:

```
pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>)> NextAction.all
=> [#<NextAction id: 4, created_at: "2014-04-20 16:53:20", updated_at: "2014-04-20 16:53:20", status: 0>,
 #<NextAction id: 5, created_at: "2014-04-20 16:53:20", updated_at: "2014-04-20 16:53:20", status: 0>,
 #<NextAction id: 6, created_at: "2014-04-20 16:53:20", updated_at: "2014-04-20 16:53:20", status: 0>]
pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>)> NextActionsOrder.all
=> [#<NextActionsOrder id: 2, next_action_id: 6, order_id: 3>,
 #<NextActionsOrder id: 3, next_action_id: 6, order_id: 4>]
pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>)> Order.all
=> [#<Order id: 3, created_at: "2014-04-20 16:53:20", updated_at: "2014-04-20 16:53:20", status: 0>,
 #<Order id: 4, created_at: "2014-04-20 16:53:20", updated_at: "2014-04-20 16:53:20", status: 0>]
```

Again, everything looks good, except now we have 2 orphan NextAction records - IDs #4 and #5.

Any ideas?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the next_action in the factory :next_actions_order, which creates an additional next_action...

I would rewrite the next_action factory using

```
after(:build) do |next_action, evaluator|
  next_action.orders << build(:order)
end
```

or

```
after(:build) do |next_action, evaluator|
  next_action.orders << build_list(:order, evaluator.orders_count)
end
```

if you need more than one.

This way the entire chain is created at once with all cross references filled in as they should! (and without doubles!)

Comment: Great, thanks, that worked!  For some reason, I thought that next_action association was needed, but clearly not.  I ended up doing `(1..evaluator.orders_count).to_a.each { next_action.orders << build(:order) }` so that I could handle the cases where I needed more than one order.

Comment: There is a better way to do that: see the second option I added to my answer!

Comment: Thanks for helping me clean that up!