# has_many through with Factory Girl error when running tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, factory-bot, factories

I've been struggling with setting up a has_many through relationship using Factory Girl.
I have two models course and category, a course can have many categories, I have two factories course and category.

I have these three models

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :history]

  has_many :categorisations
  has_many :categories, :through=> :categorisations 
  belongs_to :partner
  belongs_to :user
 # validates_uniqueness_of :title
  validates :title, presence: true
  # validates :start_date, presence: true
  # validates :duration, presence:true
  # validates :state, presence:true
  validates :categories, length: { minimum: 1 , message:"please select"}
  validates :partner_id, presence: true, allow_nil: false
end
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorisations 
  has_many :courses, :through=> :categorisations
  belongs_to :user
#validation 
  validates :name, presence: true , uniqueness: { scope: :name }
end

class Categorisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :course
end
```

Factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :course do |f|
    f.title "Introduction to Accounting short course"
    f.start_date "2014-02-27 00:00:00"
    f.duration "10 WEEKS ONLINE"
    partner 
    categorisation
   end
   # join table factory - :category
  factory :categorisation do |categorisation|
    categorisation.association :course
    categorisation.association :category
   end   
end
```

Category Factory in indiviual file

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :category do |f|
    f.name "Marketing"
  end
end
```

The error I get when the tests run is:

Partner has a valid factory for course
     Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.create(:course)).to be_valid
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Name has already been taken

What I want to do is create a course that has one or more categories, I am not to sure what i am doing wrong here but I need the course factory to be valid. I know that my category factory is valid.

It seems like it tries to create a category twice thats why it is coming up with the error of name already exists.

Comment: are there any validations for `Course#title` ? I think the problem is in your `Course`. Can you provide the `errors` of your course model?

Comment: The tests for the model without the associations it passes, i dont think it is the title

Comment: is there a uniqueness validator for the title?

Comment: No there isnt i have just validated presence, i commented out the unquieness validator

Comment: This could be a duplicate of below:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162344/rails-3-factory-girl-many-to-many-relationships][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162344/rails-3-factory-girl-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185326/factorygirl-creating-extra-records-with-has-many-association

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the course twice, once at the top and then again when you create the categorization. Because you are not linking to a previously created course, FactoryGirl is create a new one for you. If you put a break before the join line you will see what is already there and again when in the association code.

You need to add the specifics of the course in the line within the join

```
categorisation.association :course
```

e.g.

```
categorisation.association (:course, title: "Introduction to Accounting short course")
```

(sorry the syntax there maybe slightly out, but you get the idea)

Comment: Sorry just a question do i add this to my categorisation factory